# Sending more than one image with AFNetworking

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, afnetworking, multipartform-data

I'm developing a messaging app, and users can also send pictures to one another.
When a user sends more than one picture I send them in parallel (I don't wait for the first one to finish upload before I send the second one)

Before moving to `AFNetworking` I succeeded in doing this with `ASIFormDataRequest`, and indeed if I sent 2 images, both of them were transmitted in parallel and successfully delivered to the other user.

When I try doing this with AFNetworking, I get some strange behavior.
I'll try to describe the case were user1 send two images too user2:

1. User1 send image1 -> everything looks ok, I can see the upload progress.
2. User1 then send image2 -> still looks ok, I can see the upload progress of both images
3. image1 upload is finished -> user2 gets a corrupted image that looks like a combination of image1 and image2 together!
4. image2 upload is finished -> user2 gets image2 successfully

This is how I send an image

```
- (void)sendImageMsgWithPath:(NSString *)path
                       image:(UIImage *)image
                     success:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject))success
                     failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure
                    progress:(void (^)(NSInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite))progress
{
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5);

    // create the request

    NSURLRequest *request = [[AppClient sharedClient] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:path parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) 
                             {
                                 [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"image_name" fileName:@"image_name.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
                             }];


    // create the operation

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request] autorelease];

    // set progress block

    [operation setUploadProgressBlock:progress];

    //set completion blocks

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:success failure:failure];

    // set it to work in background

    [operation setShouldExecuteAsBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:nil];

    // add it to the operations queue

    [[AppClient sharedClient] enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
}
```

*** the path for both image uploads is the same:

> path =
>   @"FrontEnd?cmd=sendimage&fromuserid=3&touserid=1&"

it will be added to the baseURL to create the coplete URL:

> @"http://somename.myftp.org:8080/web_proj/FrontEnd?cmd=sendimage&fromuserid=3&touserid=1"

This are the images I sent:
image1
[image]

image2
[image]

corrupted image
[image]

Comment: make sure you are using separate buffers for each image you send. Also make sure your receiver is using separate buffers for each received image. Sounds like they are being combined somewhere. Finally, if you are sending/receiving over 3G/4G, you may not get much throughput improvement by sending all images in parallel. You will have to experiment to see how many streams are optimal.

Comment: I succeed doing this with ASIHTTPRequest library so it's probably not a server issue. About the buffers in client side, well I don't really handle this, I'm just using the AFNetworking API, not sure if the library manage that or if I need to do it...

Comment: How are you handling this in the server side? Maybe you are writing the received images into the same file: the first one starts getting overwritten by the second one, the second one is sent ok, because it has overwritten the first one completely.

Answer (score 1):

Use a multipartFormRequest for that use below method:

```
- (NSMutableURLRequest *)multipartFormRequestWithMethod:(NSString *)method
                                               path:(NSString *)path
                                         parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
                          constructingBodyWithBlock:(void (^)(id <AFMultipartFormDataProxy>formData))block;
```

For example like this:

```
 NSURLRequest* request = [[YourHTTPClient sharedHTTPClient] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST"
                     path:path
                     parameters:dict
                     constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
                          [formData appendPartWithFileData:data1
                                                      name:@"image1"
                                                      fileName:@"image1.jpg"
                                                      mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
                          [formData appendPartWithFileData:data2
                                                      name:@"image2"
                                                      fileName:@"image2.jpg"
                                                      mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
                     }
                 }];
```

Comment: But I do use multipartFormRequestWithMethod, I don't want to send two images in one request, the images are sent in two separate request...

Answer (score 1):

How are you creating the UIImage objects that get passed into your sendImageMsgWithPath: method? Are you creating them using imageWithData: (or similar)? If so, I have seen problems like this when trying to reuse an NSMutableData. It seems that even after you create the UIImage, the subsystem still needs to read that data at a later time. And if you have since reused that NSMutableData, the image will be corrupted.

If this is the case, I recommend that you use a new NSMutableData to create each UIImage.