# Objective C - Submitting HTML form

Tags: html, objective-c, post, submit

How do I write objective-C code to click this HTML submit button in iOS?

```
<input type="password" class="lp_input" size="13" name="password" autocomplete="off">
<input type="text" class="lp_input" size="13" name="username" value="" autocomplete="off">
<input name="login" id="submitform" type="submit" class="o" value="Logon">
```

I've already created a request object, but don't know how to use it to submit the above.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://connect.website.com"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[request setValue:@"text/html" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:self.userName forHTTPHeaderField:@"username"];
[request setValue:self.Password forHTTPHeaderField:@"password"];
//HOW DO I SUBMIT THIS?

NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

[connection start];

if (connection) {
    mutData = [NSMutableData data];
}
```

Comment: Try to read this:


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12658724/how-to-simulate-http-form-post-submit-on-ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

if you have a page http://test.com/form.php with following form:

```
<form name="login" method="POST" action="action.php">
    <input name="username"><br />
    <input name="password"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

you can use this code, to perform this form.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://test.com/action.php];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [[[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] autorelease];
[request setPostValue:@"Admin" forKey:@"username"];
[request setPostValue:@"1234" forKey:@"password"];
[request startSynchronous];
```

It will really help you out.

Comment: ASIFormDataRequest requires a horde of external libraries. Not to mention a few of them are incompatible with ARC mode. Isn't there a simple way to natively submit forms?

Comment: Also, when you submit a form using Objective C, do all the input fields tags within the form need to be filled? Or just the essential ones? (username/password)

Answer (score 1):

Think of what youre doing as pretending to be a browser. When the *user* submits the form in a browser, the browser posts the form data to the url in the action attribute of the form tag. So all you have to is make the same request the browser would make to the server to submit the form. Forget trying trying to pretend to be the user, pretend to be the browser and just post the form data directly to the server.