# Auto Completing Gravity Form

Tags: xcode, forms, ibeacon, gravity-forms-plugin

I am currently writting an iBeacons app, I would like to be able to automatically register people that come into the proximity of the iBeacon. A collegue of mine has set up a gravity form on our company website with the fields (first name, last name and Email address) that when filled in is then emailed to a email adress.

Is it possible to automatically get these detaisl from the users device? (For example getting the name and email for their contact card)

If it is unable to be populated automatically from the customrs device, How can I fill it in if the customer enter the details eariler on before getting into the proximity of the beacon?

Comment: How is this related to XCode? Is your question about adding data with gravity-forms? Or is it about how to get the iBeacon infos (Major/Minor/Proximity)?

Comment: I want to know how I can make the application fill in the form automatically when you are within a certain proximity of the ibeacon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have sorted this issue, I added a bit of script to the webpage that submits the details once filled in. I then have the app add what the user enteres into the text fills added to the string which I then supply a webView that loads hidden in the background and then the form is filled and the automated e-mail sent.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your app needs to take the users first name, last name and email of
   the user when they first launch it.
2. You then need to set your app to listen for beacons in the background using [region monitoring](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html).
3. When the region monitoring is triggered, your app needs send a correct http request to the gravity form handler, it should contain the name and email information.

Comment: I have the correct http link to enter the details required, but I need the link to have the submit feature of the submit button on the page.

Comment: If you construct an appropriate HTTP request you don't need to access the page first. [Here is an example of how to do it in Objective-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18691377/objective-c-submitting-html-form).