# Objective C (iOS) to jersey query params. Null issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, rest, jersey, jersey-2.0

I am learning Jersey and stumbling from one issue to another. I just got the service to work from Java client (after some help from someone here). The service class is as follows:

```
@Path("/user")
public class UserService extends AbstractService {
    private static final NouLogger logger = NouLogger
            .getLogger(UserService.class);

    @Path("fbregister")
    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    public String createNewFBUser(@FormParam("fbuserid") String userid,
            @FormParam("fbmailid") String emailId,
            @FormParam("fbfullname") String fullName,
            @FormParam("fbusertoken") String userToken,
            @Context HttpServletResponse servletResponse) throws IOException,
            DatabaseException {
        final String methodName = "createNewFBUser";

        User user = new User();
        user.setEmail(emailId);
        user.setName(fullName);
        user.setFacebookSecret(userToken);

        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = getSession();
        } catch (DatabaseException e) {
            final String message = "Error occurred while fetching session.";
            logger.error(methodName, message, e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        UserDAO userDAO = DAOFactory.DEFAULT.buildUserDAO();
        Transaction txn = session.beginTransaction();
        userDAO.save(user);
        txn.commit();
        closeSession();

        return user.getId().toString();
    }

}
```

This works fine when I call it from Java client. But when I call it from iOS code, I get all the null values for all the parameters. The iOS code is as below:

```
// To encode parameter.    
NSString *fb_userid = [user objectForKey:@"id"];
    NSString *fb_mailid = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,(CFStringRef)[user objectForKey:@"email"], NULL, (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",kCFStringEncodingUTF8 ));
    NSString *fb_fullname = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,(CFStringRef)user.name, NULL, (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",kCFStringEncodingUTF8 ));
    NSString *fbAccessToken = [[[FBSession activeSession] accessTokenData] accessToken];

    NSLog(@"user = %@", user);
    NSLog(@"fb_userid = %@", fb_userid);
    NSLog(@"fb_mailid = %@", fb_mailid);
    NSLog(@"fb_fullname = %@", fb_fullname);

// To send url Request.
    NSString *url1 =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myip:8080/nou/rest/user/fbregister?fbuserid=%@&fbmailid=%@&fbfullname=%@&fbusertoken=%@", fb_userid, fb_mailid, fb_fullname, fbAccessToken];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:url1];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    theConnection1 = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
```

Any idea why this is happening? I put it on remote debug, I could see the method being invoked also, my DB entry was created but all the null values were put in it. Help me solve this issue.

**EDIT:**

I tried sending just one parameter 'id' and it did not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your java code, you are accepting parameters as FormParam but while posting you are sending it as part of query string from the client code. So either:

1. Change the FormParam in server code to QueryParam
2. or Change the client code to send it as post params. Here is an example:
   [How to simulate HTTP form (POST) submit on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12658724/how-to-simulate-http-form-post-submit-on-ios)